# Nested controllers + views, programmatically adding constraints, which place ? best practice?

Tags: ios, constraints, swift4, nslayoutconstraint

I've got multiple questions about layout constraints/anchor best practices...

**Summary**

1. I would like to know about the best practice and maybe some explanations, where to instantiate constraints that reference parts of the parent view. I see that viewDidLoad is not good
2. Which alternatives to viewDidLoad make sense
3. But also where to put it, or what to set, so it gets called on rotation updates (some constant values are complex calculations based on given width and amount of elements and I need to recalculate then)
4. Do I need to save all my constraints in properties and reference them on update or can I call `self.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentController.view.leadingAnchor,[..])` over and over again

**My setup**

In my code I've got a nested hierarchy like this

```
rootController
view
    menuViewController
    view
        menuOneViewController
        view
            UIButton1
            UIButton2
            ...
            UIButton6
```

---

Each level has constraints in regard to anchors of it's parent level.

I started with adding the constraints in the viewDidLoad method of each Controller.

menuViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.menuOneViewController = MenuOneViewController()
    guard let menuOneViewController = self.menuOneViewController else { return }

    menuOneViewController.parentController = self

    self.view.addSubview(menuOneViewController.view)
}
```

menuOneViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let parentController = self.parentController else { return }
    let menuRowHeight = parentController.menuRowHeight

    self.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: menuRowHeight).isActive = true
    self.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentController.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    self.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentController.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    self.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentController.view.topAnchor, constant: -(menuRowHeight)).isActive = true
```

And with this setup I got this message:

```
'Unable to activate constraint with anchors 
<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600001199900 "UIView:0x7fd99e705b90.leading">
and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600001199980 "UIView:0x7fd99e526bc0.leading"> 
because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its 
anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

**My thoughts and details**

And I think I get it... I guess the hierarchy is not build yet while in the viewDidLoad method. I guess it happens after viewDidLoad(), so I would either need to move such constraints into a method in the child that is called after viewDidLoad or I could create the constraints in the parent after the addSubview call.

Now while the latter way will work for sure I'd still like to know which other place I would normally put it. And also I'd prefer to not bother the parent view controller with the logic of how big the child view controllers view should be.

So would I put such code inside `updateViewConstraints` then ? because if so, it doesn't seem to be called on rotation, which was my next concern, or do I need to set some flags or do sth. to have that triggered manually. If so, which method ?, at which level ?

Also if that method will be called twice, will I get problems because of repeated constraint generation / duplicate conflicting constraints ? What's the best practice in that case ?

Also in that regard, does it matter in any way if I use `NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, [..]).isActive = true` vs. `view.anchor.constraint(`

I first learned about NSLayoutConstraint, then about the other ways (anchors and visual format language) and right now I have a mix of anchor.constraints and NSLayoutConstraint, not sure which way to go. But as I like my code clean, I'd like to stick with one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** to add a child VC you should

```
addChildViewController(child) 
view.addSubview(child.view)
child.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
// set constraints here
child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

**Second** `viewDidLoad` is the best ealier place for that , regarding rotation auto-layout adjusts itself when the device rotate , but if you want to tweak something make it as a var constraint and adjust it inside

```
func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, 
               with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {}
```

Also **Apple** recommends using anchors because it's automatically add the constraint to the appropriate parent , plus use `NSLayoutConstraint.activate([-,-,-,])` to activate many constraints instead of putting `.active = true` at each one

Comment: this works, also the viewWillTransition now works (I'm pretty sure I tried it before, but maybe the addChild call was needed). what is the didMove for ? thank you

Comment: also thanks because the addChildViewController, now I can also get rid of ```menuOneViewController.parentController = self```

Comment: yes , remove it also look here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmove

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that `viewDidLoad()` is being called before `menuOneViewController`'s view is added to `menuViewController`'s view. This is why you are getting the `...because they have no common ancestor` runtime error.

The larger problem and solution is that the child should not know about the view it is being constrained in. Not only does this reduce the reusability of the component `menuOneViewController`, but it will also make it more difficult to debug in the future. Your constraints should be set in `menuViewController` after adding `mainOneViewController`'s view as a subview. Also, you'll save yourself some space by using [`NSLayoutConstraint.activate(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526955-activate), as well as [`.constraint(equalTo:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor/1500946-constraint) without the `constant:` argument.

Here is the `viewDidLoad()` override for `menuViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.menuOneViewController = MenuOneViewController()
    guard let menuOneViewController = self.menuOneViewController else { return }

    menuOneViewController.parentController = self

    self.view.addSubview(menuOneViewController.view)

    let subView = menuOneViewController.view
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints: [
        subView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: menuRowHeight),
        subView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor)
        subView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
        subView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: -menuRowHeight)
    ]
}
```

Comment: Note that you also need to use @Sk_Khan 's answer as well.